# R Anova() for backwards model selection: should test = F or chisq?

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model

When performing an anova comparing two models (glm or lm, sometimes (g)lmer) should I use test="Chisq" or test="F"? Or what criteria should I use to chose the test?

Answer (score 0):

[Don't do stepwise regression at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/1352)

---

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5004/1352) for a general motivation for an answer that essentially says that "the question is wrong".)

(See [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) for a motivation for short answers. Longer answers are always welcome.)